# How to use smart pointers in a simple tree implementation

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, b-tree

This is a node for B+ tree. I wanted to use smart pointers as my program is leaking a lot of memory. How can convert the code by using smart pointers ?

```
class node
{

public:

    long* key;
    int capacity;
    node** nodes;
    node* parent;
    long* value;

    node ( int order ) {
        key = new long[order + 1];
        value = new long[order + 1];
        nodes = new node *[order + 2];
        capacity = 0;
        parent = NULL;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= order + 1; i++ ) {
            this->nodes[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~node() {
        delete[] key;
        delete[] value;
        for ( int i = 0; i <= order + 1; i++ ) {
            delete nodes[i];
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: It's leaking memory because you do not define a destructor `node::~node()` to clean up a node when it is deleted.  If you do not understand this, then trying to move to smart pointers is not a good idea.

Comment: @paddy i do understand destructor i think i copied the code from previous revision. sorry for that i will update it.

Comment: `delete [] nodes` does not delete the pointers.  You have to do that in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use smart pointers. Be smart and *don't* use pointers, but rather *containers*:

```
#include <vector>

struct node
{
    std::vector<long>   keys;
    std::vector<long>   values;

    std::vector<node *> nodes;
    node *              parent;
};
```

Depending on the constraints of your structure I might even wish to make `parent` a `node &` (if the parent always comes first and never changes), or maybe a `std::reference_wrapper<node>`. But that's a minor quibble.)

Comment: Ya i too thought so but i was trying to compare performance of different dictionary data structures and using containers might reduce the performance as it might make memory allocation and deallocation several more times internally.

Comment: @hellcoderz: The allocation behaviour of `vector` is clearly specified. It certainly needs to be no worse than your own code, and may quite possibly be better.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it, and also getting it right wrt. single key versus many (instead of fixing my answer when i noticed, i just deleted)

Comment: It's not clear to me (from the question) who actually owns the child nodes, but it may still be a good idea to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>>` instead of a `vector<node *>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: *The allocation behaviour of vector [...] needs to be no worse than your own code, and may quite possibly be better.* That is a tough statement that you can probably not backup. The requirements of `vector` are *amortized constant time*, while the code in the question makes exactly 1 allocation. Of course, you can control that by *reserving* or *resizing*, but it cannot be made *better* (in the sense of more efficient), as much *equivalent* which is more than enough considering that it simplifies code.

Comment: Also note that in this proposed solution some of the memory must still be managed manually (in particular the `node*`'s inside the `std::vector`) and that this can be easily simplified by using smart pointers: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>`, which can be combined with `std::make_shared` to reduce the overall number of allocations. Another improvement would be creating a composed type with the key-value pair and holding a single vector of those, which will further reduce the number of separate allocations.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I was implying the use of `reserve` and `capacity`, which do give you guarantees when allocations happen and when they can't happen. I should have said that you need to use the vector correctly (it's not blindly always better). But correct code that solves the OP's problem will be no worse than what the OP has now.